# How to properly import tcl file

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I am trying to use the Azure theme in a tkinter application i made. I used the code from github to import the theme(https://github.com/rdbende/Azure-ttk-theme). I put the "azure.tcl" file in the folder with the python file and got the error "_tkinter.TclError: couldn't read file "./theme/light.tcl": no such file or directory". I then tried making a simpler tkinter program with the same ttk theme import code from before but this time in it's own folder with the tcl file. I still got the same error message. When i download the file from github, i ran the example python file and worked just fine.

Here is the code i use to import the file.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Label, ttk


root = tk.Tk()

root.tk.call("source", "azure.tcl")
root.tk.call("set_theme", "dark")

root.geometry("300x300")

L1 = Label(root, text="Hello world")

L1.grid(row=1, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Did you copy the `theme` folder from the theme repository as well?

Comment: @acw1668 Yes, the themes folder is in the same folder.

Comment: I don't have such issue.  The error is "theme/light.tcl" not found, did you check whether this file exists?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have this "TKinterModernThemes" library, then you should also install it with below code:

`pip install TKinterModernThemes`

Then, you can keep your script as it is but just a few arrangements.

1. Importing Library:

   `import TKinterModernThemes as TKMT`
2. Threat like `window.root` is your `tk.Tk()` object:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Label, ttk
import TKinterModernThemes as TKMT

window = TKMT.ThemedTKinterFrame("%yourProjectName","azure","dark")

window.root.geometry("300x300")

L1 = Label(window.root, text="Hello world")

L1.grid(row=1, column=1)

window.root.mainloop()
```